# How can I move apps to the external SD card on LG Optimus 2X P990?

Tags: app2sd, lg-optimus-2x

I have put a SD 16 GB in my LG Optimus 2X P990, but it seems that the phone won't save on it. Is it possible to save/move apps to the external SD card? Or even set it to do it automatically? I have already formatted the SD card twice, and it still is not working properly.

Answer (score 2):

Try [App 2 SD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.a0soft.gphone.app2sd), it should be able to move at least some of the apps. 
To set it to automatic, you will need the android SDK (to use `adb`). From [here](http://techgage.com/article/moving_your_non-movable_android_apps_to_an_sd_card), those commands should work (worked for me on my Samsung Galaxy Ace):

> **adb devices**
>
> Probes Android devices connected to the PC. Do this first to assure that the phone is being detected.
>
> **adb shell pm getInstallLocation**
>
> This results in a numerical value to state where the default install location is (0: phone, 2: external).
>
> **adb shell pm setInstallLocation 2**
>
> This sets the default install location to the external storage.